# Can a GPS waypoint be used when filing a VFR flight plan?

Tags: visual-flight-rules, gnss, flight-plans

This probably equally applies to IFR flight plans, but the general question is can arbitrary (unrelated to an airway or named fix) GPS coordinates be used in the route on a flight plan?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you mean lat/ lon coordinates provided by the pilot, or official pre-defined waypoints published by the FAA (if in the US)? See comments below other answers for more.

Comment: @quietflyer Question updated. Whether or not they relate to a defined waypoint probably wouldn't matter, I'm just asking if they will accept lat/long coordinates in the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The AIM specifies how flight plans should be filled out](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim.pdf), block 8 contains the route of flight:

> 8. Block 8. Define the route of flight by **using NAVAID identifier codes and airways**

It is possible to do this if you can fly at or above FL390, since you need to get through class A airspace to get to FL390 you can not get to FL390 on a VFR flight plan alone.

> Pilots of aircraft equipped with latitude/ longitude coordinate
>   navigation capability, independent of VOR/TACAN references, may file
>   for random RNAV routes at and above FL 390 within the conterminous
>   U.S. using the following procedures.
>
> ...
>
> Define the route of flight after the departure fix, including each
>   intermediate fix (turnpoint) and the arrival fix for the destination
>   airport in terms of latitude/longitude coordinates plotted to the
>   nearest minute

Comment: I don't think there is anything in what you quoted that precludes a pilot from filing VFR below FL 390 using GPS waypoints.

Comment: @MichaelHall _"may file for random RNAV routes **at and above FL 390**"_

Comment: @MichaelHall the way I read the question was if pilots can file with arbitrary lat/long points _"can GPS coordinates be used"_, defined waypoints are aloud.

Comment: The AIM only references RNAV under the IFR filing section, for VFR it does not discuss it. But if we assume that anything it's ok to do on an IFR flight plan route is also ok on a VFR route, then it does say this about RNAV: "(e) Define the random route by waypoints. File route description waypoints by using degree-distance fixes based on navigational aids which are appropriate for the altitude stratum."

Comment: @hemp since its above FL390 you would not be able to get there any other way than an IFR flight plan as you would need to go through Class A airspace.

Comment: @Dave, I'm not sure if you are agreeing or disagreeing with me...  "May", or being allowed to do something in one scenario doesn't restrict that same thing from another scenario.  Is there a specific restriction against using GPS waypoints under VFR?  If so, quote that.  If not, by default it is permitted.

Comment: @MichaelHall I guess what Im saying is that its a logic trap, the IFR permission is only for flights above FL390 which you can only get to on an IFR flight plan (Through class A). The VFR flight plan regulations for filling out Block 8 clearly state that only NAVAID id codes and airways are to be used (above quote). The latter part only applies to IFR as its written even though it does not explicitly state it.

Comment: And what I am saying is that the word "only" does not appear in your quote.  Consider the following two statements:  "The AIM only mentions filing VFR using airways and NAVAIDS."  And:  "The AIM states that when filing VFR you can only use airways and NAVAIDS."  Similar, yet very different meanings.  And only the first one is true.

Comment: @Dave, the section of AIM I referenced is not with regard to FL390, it is a general purpose statement about RNAV and states that you would use fix/radial/distance notation (not lat/long coordinates.) The section for FL390 and above is the only place I've seen where lat/long coordinates are discussed as being acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, nothing prevents you from doing so, and it is quite common.

Flying VFR does not require you to actually navigate by means of visual reference, it just requires you to remain VMC in accordance with the airspace class you are in.

Comment: What is the format for GPS coordinates that Leidos Flight Services will accept?

Comment: @hemp Don't know what Leidos Flight Service is, but the format to use in flightplans is standard WGS84 DMS coordinates, such as 382338N 0763251W

Comment: Leidos Flight Service, formerly known as Lockheed Martin Flight Service, is the official FAA flight plan filing service (1800WXBrief). Is there a reference somewhere stating that WGS84 is the correct format to use? The AIM says "Record latitude/longitude coordinates by four figures describing latitude in degrees and minutes followed by a solidus and five figures describing longitude in degrees and minutes." under 5-1-8.

Comment: @hemp I really don't know about rules for just one specific country. You should have specified in your question if you were asking specifically about the USA. Regardless, WGS84 is the standard format used for aviation worldwide.

Comment: Do you have a reference that specifies WGS84 as the standard format used for aviation worldwide?

Comment: @hemp ... any aviation document you will ever find that contains geographical coordinates

Comment: Considering I just directed you to one that uses a different format, that seems like a bogus answer.

Comment: @hemp DMS is the format. WGS84 is the Geodetic System.